# How long should mortar/stucco cure before painting?

Tags: painting, masonry

I need to tuckpoint mortar on some old bricks before I prime and paint them. I heard that cement products (concrete, mortar etc) need to "cure" for several weeks before coating. How long should it cure before painting?

Comment: "several weeks" sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

My stucco guy says 1-2 weeks, depending on weather. (Warm and dry is faster.)

If you have a chance, get a concrete-specific primer.

Comment: I use gray Zinsser